# Xcode 9.0.1 Blank space in Ipad air 2 (11.0.1)

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode

My application appears a white blank space (between Green space and Grey space at image) when i built it through Xcode 9 and 9.0.1 to iOS 11 (iPad air 2). I thought this problem cause Xcode 9, however I re-build to iOS 10 then that white blank space didn't appear.
What should i do to fix this problem?

[image: Screen of Simulator]

Comment: Do you have a background image in background?

Comment: `a white blank space (between Green space and Grey space at image)` what view contains it ? It's an `UIView` or an `UIImageView`. You need to explain more clearly.

Comment: Oh. They are UIView. The white blank space only appear when i build to iOS 11 device.

Comment: @TúTrần so normally, in iOS 10 do you have any space (between Green space and Grey space?